# Jquery plugins won't work in dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, loaded

i got this code to dynamically load html BUT i got a problem cause my plugins work fine on index.html but when you change page it no longer works..anyone who can help me out? thnx

$(function() {

```
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;


$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });


    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

});

Comment: What's with 'load(newHash + " #guts"'? Why is #guts in there?

Comment: A sample of you DOM would help too.

Comment: the plugins on the page which gets loaded don't work..for example im loading a page where lightbox plugin is used to show videos but the plugin won't do its thing. #guts is the div where the content gets loaded in basically.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is .live() if you want to attached jQuery to dynamically created markup.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: yea that sounds like the solution but when i try and replace .bind() with .live() nothing works anymore..